# Angular Datatables: cannot call destroy/edit function

Tags: datatables, angular-datatables

I cannot access the API methods mentioned in this [doc](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/api), as well as the destroy method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521000/how-to-call-the-destroy-function-of-angular-datatables#) .

the HTML:

```
<table datatable dt-instance="dtInstance" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table-striped">
            </table>
```

In my controller I have:

```
    a.dtInstance = {};

    var getTableData = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(tablecontent_array); 

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    a.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise( getTableData())
            .withPaginationType('full_numbers');

    a.dtColumns = [
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID').notVisible(), //
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('groupby').withTitle('Group By').notSortable(),
                    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('value').withTitle('value').notSortable()
                ]
```

> 'tablecontent_array' contains the data.

When I try to modify/destroy the table I get an error.

```
a.dtInstance.rerender()
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: a.dtInstance.rerender is not a function
```

My aim is to modify the table after certain user operations. The table data in rendering fine. But I cannot access any of its API methods.

May be I am doing some mistake while doing so, I am new to angular-datatable, any help/suggestions regarding this issue will be helpful.

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for this, but hard to guess what exactly you have done wrong - can you show the full code or setup a plnkr or fiddle that reproduces the problem? The misbehaviour is not caused by the code provided in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dwelling into the question for days I tried creating plnkr as suggested in the comment. It turns out I was not using the correct versions of datatables, Angular and host of other Libraries. Corrected that and the issue was resolved.

Even then my objective of adding/appending new column(s) was not resolved in angular way. However some folks posted possible solutions using jquery datatables.